# Can I have help on this error showing up on my Youtube-dl npm Project

Tags: javascript, html, npm, youtube

I have this error when I run the code for this program to download video from youtube, using the youtube-dl npm. I'm guessing but not sure tho this error is due to the fact that i'm pressing a button to call the action so it doesn't see the actual Link. But i'm clearly not sure (And I don't know how to fix this) So here is my code and the error.

```
<input class="inputT" type="text" id="ytLink" />
<button class="checkLinkYb" type="button" onclick="youtubeDL()">
  Télécharger
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var youtubeLink = document.getElementById("ytLink").value;

  function youtubeDL() {
    console.log("Downloading " + document.getElementById("ytLink").value);
    var fs = require("fs");
    var youtubedl = require("youtube-dl");
    var video = youtubedl(youtubeLink, ["--format=18"], { cwd: __dirname });
    video.on("info", function(info) {
      console.log("Download started");
      console.log("filename: " + info._filename);
      console.log("size: " + info.size);
    });
    video.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("myvideo.mp4"));
  }
</script>
```

Here the error I get:

```js
events.js:167 Uncaught Error: Command failed
: F:\Python Java C\Electron\ErnestCorp\resources\app\node_modules\youtube-dl\bin\youtube-dl.exe 
--dump-json --format=18 --encoding utf8 -- 
ERROR: '' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" 
(or run  youtube-dl "ytsearch:" ) to search YouTube

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:299)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251)
```

Comment: You have to validate first that yuo're passing a URL, in this case, you're not passing any URL, hence the error: `ERROR: '' is not a valid URL`.

Comment: But in fact I'am, Because I created a Input box called "ytLink" here : <input class="inputT" type="text" id="ytLink" />. And I call it as youtubeLink in the youtube downloader url : var video = youtubedl(youtubeLink, ["--format=18"], { cwd: __dirname }); //no ?